# ISO 8583 packing 120 feild

Tags: java, iso, pack, iso8583, jpos

I want to set sub feilds of 120, can anyone guide ?

Currently I am using JPOS library for packing data, here is the below sample pack message.

```
        request.setPackager(packager);
        request.setMTI(Constants.MTI.FINANCIAL_RESPONSE.getValue());
        request.set(new ISOField(2, unpackedMsg.getString(2)));
        request.set(new ISOField(3, "000062"));
        request.set(new ISOField(4, unpackedMsg.getString(4)));
        request.set(new ISOField(7, unpackedMsg.getString(7)));
        request.set(new ISOField(11, unpackedMsg.getString(11)));
        request.set(new ISOField(12, unpackedMsg.getString(12)));
        request.set(new ISOField(13, unpackedMsg.getString(13)));
        request.set(new ISOField(15, unpackedMsg.getString(15)));
        request.set(new ISOField(18, unpackedMsg.getString(18)));
        request.set(new ISOField(22, unpackedMsg.getString(22)));
        request.set(new ISOField(24, unpackedMsg.getString(24)));
        request.set(new ISOField(32, unpackedMsg.getString(32)));
        request.set(new ISOField(33, unpackedMsg.getString(33)));
        request.set(new ISOField(37, unpackedMsg.getString(37)));
        request.set(new ISOField(38, Constants.getRandomNumberString()));
        request.set(new ISOField(39, Constants.SUCCESS_RESPONSE));
        request.set(new ISOField(41, unpackedMsg.getString(41)));
        request.set(new ISOField(43, unpackedMsg.getString(43)));
        request.set(new ISOField(49, unpackedMsg.getString(49)));
        request.set(new ISOField(103, unpackedMsg.getString(103)));
        request.set(new ISOField(120, sb.toString()));
```

Want to add data under sub fields of 120.

[120 feild values should be as mentioned in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6frPU.png)

Comment: what message are you building ? seems a 1110 but can't be sure. I don't remember what's the field 120 is for, IIRC is for private acquiring data, probably it's an LLLvar, containing subfields, you should have some specific documentation about it.

Comment: can you please share any dummy code for packing 120 feild with sub fields as well?

Comment: Can you explain what error you are getting while setting field 120 in the excerpt in your code.

Comment: can you guide, how can i set multiple feilds of 120 i.e 120.1,120.2,120.3 etc? using Jpos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with MLI, The length wasn't appropriate when i have sent to 3rd party.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).